# some confusions about extreme set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

In Rudin's book "Functional Analysis",he defined an extreme set (called $S$) of $K$(in a topological vector space $X$) if no point of $S$ is an internal point of any lime interval whose end points are in $K$,except when both end points are in $S$.And analytically,the condition can be expressed as follows:If $x,y\in K$,$0<t<1$,and $$(1-t)x+ty\in S,$$ then $x\in S$ and $y\in S$.

What's the essence did Rudin want to say? I will get that if both end points of any line lie in $S$,then the whole line belongs to $S$,that's amazing to me for that the $S$ may be so large!

Secondly,he defined that the extreme points of $K$ are the extreme sets that consist of just one point.As to the definition of extreme set,what does an extreme set look like if it consist of just one point?

Thirdly,I want to verify that the closed unit ball of $L^1$(relative to Lebesgue measure on the unit interval) has no extreme points.But I don't know how to start.Can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps it might help to prove this: The set of extreme points of the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the unit sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first two questions, look at some pictures.

Consider the square $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, -1 \leq x,y \leq 1\}$: It has precisely the following extreme subsets: The square itself, the four sides and the four corners. Look at some familiar convex solids. The tetrahedron, the cube, a prism, etc. and determine their extreme subsets.

In contrast, look at a circle, a half-sphere, a cylinder a cone. What are the extreme subsets?

Intuitively, extreme sets are "faces" (of arbitrary dimension) of a convex set. The extreme points are those points of the convex set that do *not* lie in any non-trivial face of a convex set.

For your questions about $L^1$, consider some examples first. If $f$ is a strictly positive continuous function with integral $1$, take a function $g \neq 0$ such that $\int g =0$ and $f \pm g \gt 0$, for example $g(x) = c \cdot \sin(2\pi x)$. Observe that $\lVert f \rVert_1 = \lVert f \pm g\rVert_1 = 1$ and $f = \frac12 (f+g) + \frac12 (f-g)$. This idea can be generalized by taking a set of positive measure where $f \geq 2\varepsilon$, say. Cut this set into two pieces $A$ and $B$ and play the same game as before by taking $g = \varepsilon (\chi_A - \chi_B)$.